# How to subclass the default `db.Model` to use as a custom `Base` with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask application spread across modules with blueprints.
Each module/blueprint has its own models.py file where models are defined.

With my desktop applications, using SQLAlchemy API directly, I would subclass `object` to define a `Base` class with some columns (ex: `id`, `date_created` ..), which then would serve as my declarative base (ex: `Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)`).

- How can I subclass `flask-SQLALchemy`'s `db.Model` so that I can use it as a Base with default columns which I want all tables to have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply set [`__abstract__`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#abstract) to `True`:

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
```

Comment: DazWorrall, thank you! I skipped that I suppose, didn't know about it. Quick question: in Flask (with flask-sqlalchemy etc) if I want to use `func` (i.e.: `func.current_timestamp`) how do I import it? PS. I can't accept the answer for another 6 minutes according to SO. I will do so once time limit expires.

Comment: `from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import current_timestamp`? [See more here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html). You can also `import sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func as func`

Comment: The link is broken. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#abstract